# Display polygon coordinates inserted from keyboard

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Polygon {
  private:

     int nrVarfuri, x[10], y[10];

  public:
    Polygon(){}
    Polygon(const Polygon &p){}

    void show()
    {
        cout<<"Number of tips: "<<nrVarfuri<<endl;

        for(int i=1;i<=nrVarfuri;i++){
            cout<<"X ["<<i<<"]="<<x[i]<<endl;
            cout<<"Y ["<<i<<"]="<<y[i]<<endl;
        }
    };
    void setValues (int nrVal, int XO[], int YO[]){
        nrVarfuri = nrVal;
        for(int i=1;i<=nrVal;i++){
            x[i]=XO[i];
            y[i]=YO[i];
        }
    };
};

int main ()
{
    int poly,i,tips,j;
    int x[tips],y[tips];
    cout<<"Insert the number of polygons: "<<endl;cin>>poly;

    Polygon tabPoligon[poly];
    Polygon p;
    for(i=0;i<poly;i++){
       // cout<<"Insert the number of tips: "<<endl; cin>>tips;
        cout<<"Numarul de varfuri: "<<endl; cin>>tips;
        for(j=1;j<=tips;j++)
        {
            cout<<"X["<<j<<"]:";cin>>x[j];
            cout<<"Y["<<j<<"]:";cin>>y[j];
        }
        p.setValues(tips,x,y);
        tabPoligon[i]=p;

    for(int i=0;i<poly;i++){
     cout<<"\n\nThe polygon have the folowing coordinates: "<<endl;

    }
     tabPoligon[i].show();

  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have to insert the number of figures, insert the coordinates from keyboard and print them. The program is showing the coordinates after reading them from keyboard and is not waiting to insert the another polygon coordinates, what is the issue?

Comment: Try moving the `}` which is before `return 0;` up: it should be just after `tabPoligon[i]=p;`

Comment: I moved the  `tabPoligon[i].show();`  before the `}` and now it's working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have numerous problems in your code. The 2 majors are:

- Variable length arrays are not allowed in C++: `int x[tips],y[tips];` is likely to initialize an array of size 1 or 0, same for `Polygon tabPoligon[poly];`
- indexes run from 0 in C++ : `for(j=1;j<=tips;j++)` should be `for(j=0;j<tips;j++)` (in many places)

This 2 problems are enough to write past the actual end of your arrays invoking *Undefined Behaviour*.

Once this is fixed, you will just have to close the first `for(i=0...)` loop used to load the data before opening the showing one as suggested by alexeykuzmin0 in its comment.

For the arrays, a quick fix would be to use const dimension as you do in your class: `int x[10], y[10]`. For the `tabPolygon` array, you could use dynamic allocation:

```
Polygon *tabPoligon = new Polygon[poly];
```

and do not forget to free it before return with `delete[] tabPoligon;`

But the C++ way would be to use a `std::vector` here.